# Can Only add one object to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios

I have a datepicker and a UIBarButtonItem, when the UIBarButtonItem is pressed it invokes a method to add the selected date to an NSMutableDictionary. The code is shown below:

```
diaryDateArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:diaryDate, nil];
NSString *dateKeyStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dateKey%d", dicDates.count+1];
diaryKeyStrArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dateKeyStr, nil];
dicDates = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:diaryDateArr forKeys:diaryKeyStrArr];
NSArray * allKeys = [dicDates allKeys];
for(NSString *key in [dicDates allKeys]) { NSLog(@"%@",[dicDates objectForKey:key]);}
NSLog(@"Count : %d", [allKeys count]);
```

However, it all seemingly works until I count how many keys are within the NSMutableDictionary and count is returned as 1, even if i click the button twice of two different dates which should theoretically (or at least how i would like to) should add another date which is selected in the date picker making the count 2. but it never changes from 1

How are the objects and keys not being placed into the dictionary?

Regards

Comment: Why do you think that a key count of 1 means 0 entries?

Comment: good point. i'm not sure why i've put that my mistake, i'll edit it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count is returning the number of entries in the dictionary - One. You can access it by doing: `[dicDates valueForKey:diaryKeyStrArr];`

If you click the button a second time, your dictionary is being set to a new one. Try this perhaps:

```
if (!dicDates) {
    dicDates = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:diaryDateArr forKeys:diaryKeyStrArr];
} else {
    dicDates[dateKeyStr] = diaryDateArr;
}
```

Comment: Right so an entry is being added I see, but why is it that only one entry is being added when I click the button, and not 1 entry 2 entries 3 entries ect ect.

Comment: It looks like you are creating a new NSDictionary each time the method is called - which means the old one is being overridden. If this is the case, move the dictionary to be an @property, like `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary * dicDates` and then access it like _dicDates in your method.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that something was being overwritten just not the dictionary itself but the object inside the dictionary. The thing that's weird is that I already have it set as
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *dicDates;
Then synthesised

Comment: If that's the case, don't initialize it every time. See update.

Comment: I tried your updated code but have a terminating error
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (1)'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Is this suggesting a key is being added but not an object?

Comment: Correct, it means that those are not equal - I'd check your code to make sure both objects "exist" (are not nil) when being added to the dictionary.
Also, you may want to just set the key to be a string "dateKey1" and the object to be the date, rather than arrays.

Comment: I changed them to be added to arrays as I was receiving pointer errors for example - Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSDate *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSArray *'

Comment: I think you may be right on some objects being nil, I'm going to try and log the date object to see if a date is even being stored..

Comment: I don't know why the Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSDate *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSArray * error happens as I thought it's possible to place NSDate and NSString into a dictionary?

Comment: It is possible, but that error happens when you set an NSArray to equal an NSDate, which you don't want to do.
If you post some more code (the entire method being called, and the @properties you have defined), we may be able to help some more. It's a little hard to see all the moving parts.

Comment: Well I thought I'd trial and error using the arrays again and turns out it works! Counts are successfully being added, but it seems only when the date object and keyStr are added to separate arrays first..

Comment: Indeed it is! I believe it was down to the nil objects and in the end it was because I was trying to use an instance variable that had no date inside. I was trying to add the object 'date1' which gets its value from 'date2' but I had forgot to say date1 = date2 at the top of the method :D

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into all of this for me @Wayfarer.